# Set the port for docker-compose.yml at runtime

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file in one of my projects where I link multiple containers to build one application. The main entry point (i.e. a container with a web server) is run on host port `8080`.

Now this port is hard-coded into the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Is there a way to dynamically set this port using runtime parameters? I could not find anything on this in the documentation, but on the other hand I can not imagine that this should not be possible.

Is it?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1377 should help eventually.

Answer (score 2):

This question is super old, but it's been viewed a bunch of times so I'll post the link to the docs for using environment variables:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose a port dynamically from compose `ports` directive, you can use environment variables in said directive, making sure you actually have those variables loaded for docker engine, example:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  abcservice:
    ports:
      - "${ENV_API_PORT}:3000"
```

```
# .env
ENV_API_PORT=8082
```

To load those variables for docker engine, pass the .env file reference via `--env-file` option instead of loading them into your shell:

```
docker-compose --env-file .env up
```

And so make sure to always pass that option when calling `docker-compose` commands.